# Apple Mac image on Amazon EC2?

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2

I found that to start with apple app development you need to have some sort of Mac. 
I wonder if one may load an image of an Mac OSx on an Amazon EC2 instance for this purpose.

Comment: You can now host macOS instances in Amazon AWS EC2: https://www.theverge.com/2020/12/1/21754843/amazon-mac-os-aws-cloud-developers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not going to work.  EC2 uses [Xen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xen) for its virtualization technology, and the chance of a Mac Xen port is pretty much nil, due to Apple's famously tight control over their operating system.  Your best bet is probably to pony up for a Mac Mini; they're relatively cheap and could make a good starter dev box.

You want a local one anyway.  You'll be running IDEs and a bunch of interactive utilities; latency from using a remote desktop will make everything just that much more difficult.

Comment: AWS has moved to a new hypervisor based on KVM and it has dumped the Xen hypervisor