# Is it possible to access Mac OS X 10.6+ by installing it on a Cloud?

Tags: macos, hosting, vmware, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do on-demand Mac OS X cloud services exist, comparable to Amazon's EC2 on-demand instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308039/do-on-demand-mac-os-x-cloud-services-exist-comparable-to-amazons-ec2-on-demand)

I am a windows user and love to do iPhone Programming for which I need a Mac. I run MAC OS X 10.5 using VMWare on my PC, but have certain limitations and its pretty slow.

So, I was trying to explore the options to have the Mac OS X 10.6 available online for development. My questions are:

1. Can I have a hosting which I can access it via Remote Desktop and run Mac on the server? If so, please tell me the options.
2. Is there a hosting available with pre-installed Mac OS X 10.6?
3. Is there any available option for online development which can be used remotely?
4. I am a bit confused with the terms : `web-hosting`, `shared-hosting`, `virtual-dedicated-server` and such similar terms which normally appear on hosting providers' site. Can somebody tell me in brief or share relevant links for me to learn more about them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My personal opinion: just get a Mac mini. They're affordable and much less hassle.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, but I wish to explore an online option, without investing a considerable amount initially. I am thinking of buying a MAC later next year... but I'd still like to compare the investment and would surely like to know something related to my question... :-)